# Initializing multiple Lists in java simultaneously

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to initialize a List in Java but I want to know if there's a more elegant way of initializing multiple lists with the same types.

So far I've done the following:

```
    List<Model> list1 = new List<>();
    List<Model> list2 = new List<>();
    List<Model> list3 = new List<>();
```

But I'm trying to initialize about 10 different lists of the same type and it seems very ugly.

I've also tried doing:

```
    List<Model> list1, list2, list3 = new List<>();
```

But this doesn't work.

After searching for the answer, all I could find were tips on how to initialize an array with multiple variables in one line using the `asList()` method but that's not what I'm trying to do.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Thats fine how you did it in first place.

Comment: @Nidhoegger Yeah I know it works, but I was just asking if there was more of an elegant way of intializing multiple Lists of the same type

Comment: Tip : For starters, consider using a `Map<String,List<Model>>`  and populate it in a `for` loop.

Comment: List is an interface so that you cannot instantiate it. Then you need to add a generic to the constructor
For example 

List<String> list1, list2, list3 = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: `List` is abstract and cannot be instantiated. You will have to use `ArrayList`. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`List` is an interface (abstract type) and cannot be instantiated. You will have to use `ArrayList` as shown below. You can try:

```
List<Model> list1 = new ArrayList<Model>(), list2 = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

Comment: It was typo ;) fixed it now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `Map` where the `key` represents the list name and the `value` represents a `List`

```
Map<String,List<Model>> lists = new HashMap<>();
```

You can then populate the list in a `for` loop :

```
for(int i=0;i<10;++i) {
    lists.put("list"+(i+1),new ArrayList<Model>());
}
```

You can access the lists using :

```
  lists.get("list1").add(new Model(...));
  lists.get("list2").add(new Model(...));
```

Disclaimer : I have not tried compiling this code since I am not on a computer.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Can you elaborate why? Would you rather create 10 variables?

Comment: I think the problem with this is that I don't want to name my list as 1,2,and 3 and the way I'm understanding this is that if I want to name it as let's say "listOne", then "listTwo" I'd have to do some checks of which index is current to determine the name I want to put it as

Comment: See my comment at Tagi Valeevs post

Comment: Can the downvoter please explain why this was downvoted? I suggest the downvoter to read this " : http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Answer (score 3):

If you have 10 lists or whatever, it's time to think: probably you need an array or list of lists.

```
List<List<Model>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) lists.add(new ArrayList<>());

// later in code instead of list5.add(...)    
lists.get(5).add(...)
```

Comment: This is the best and simplest solution to the problem, unless your lists have specific meanings and should not be indexed.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman Humans are better at remembering names. Numbers are for computers. That's why a valid variable name must contain atleast one character. That's why Java has boolean instead of `1` and `0`. That's why people use an `Enum`.

Comment: So be it. Mapping or listing strongly depends on the use case, and here it is clearly listing for me.

Comment: @BinkanSalaryman I can't argue with what your point of view. You shoudn't with someone elses.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as well

```
List<Model> list1 = new ArrayList<Model>(), list2 = new ArrayList<Model>(), list3 = new ArrayList<Model>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest possible thing that you can do is following

```
List<Model> a = new ArrayList<>(), b = new ArrayList<>(), c = new ArrayList<>(), d = new ArrayList<>();
```

But either of the approach you consider has same memory consumption impact.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
List<Model>[] lists = new List[3];
for(List list : lists) {
    list = new ArrayList<Model>();
}
List<Model> list1 = lists[0];
List<Model> list2 = lists[1];
List<Model> list3 = lists[2];
```